# Getting json data from URL when calling a function

Tags: java, android, json, xml, android-studio

I'm working on java for Android to create a function so I can use to call to fetch my mailbox using json.

When I try this:

```
public void getInbox () {
    TextView show_text = findViewById(R.id.txt_show);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_STATUS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = prefs.getString("userEmail", "SAMPLE");
    String password = prefs.getString("userPassword", "SAMPLE");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    // GET
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/inbox.php?email="+email+"&password="+password);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        show_text.setText("" + code);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        show_text.setText("failed 5");
    }
}
```

It will not connect to the url as it will jump on the catch exception following by this line:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    show_text.setText("failed 5");
}
```

So my question is do I have to use something like this?

```
private class getInbox extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            // my code goes here
```

Or do I have use like this?

private void getInbox() {

```
   // progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                       // my code goes here
```

If not could you please show me an example how I could use a function to connect to the url?

I have tried on Google to find the answers, but I couldn't find the answer what I am looking for.

Comment: Instead of handling everything manually I suggest you to use a library like [retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [volley](https://github.com/google/volley)

Comment: @jameido Thank you for this, in what method I could use on a library like retrofit or volley to allow me to use it on public void getInbox function to connect to url to fetch the json data? if you could post some example code that would be great.

Comment: I suggest you to read the documentation from one of them, it contains also examples that will help with your issue. I can't write the code you need myself.